# `ExternalEvaluate` for NumPy: passing numpy arrays

Tags: interoperability, external-calls, python

As `ExternalEvaluate` for python has been introduced recently in V11.2, what is the best practice for passing data between Mathematica and NumPy?

As by default, the Numpy arrays won't be recognised by Mathematica due to the limitation in only accepting original Python data structures.

Comment: Great to know that since v11.3 numpy arrays can be directly passed from python to Mathematica!